# Time stuck at 0f after menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I have a menu that triggers when the player enters a trigger. But the menu closes with a back button. I have Time.timeScale = 1f; in the code, but it stays paused.

I am trying to make a menu for an isometric game, where the player can go to the front door, and a menu pops up for sleep or for the shop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HouseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
public GameObject HouseMenuUI;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Doorway)
{
    if(Doorway.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        if (GameIsPaused)
        {
            OutHouse();
        }
        else
        {
            InHouse();
        }
    }
}


public void OutHouse()
{
    HouseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameIsPaused = false;
}

void InHouse()
{
    HouseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameIsPaused = true;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the player character using unscaledDeltaTime to move? If not then I see no way for the OutHouse() function to be invoked. You mention that this window can be closed with a button... does this button call the OutHouse() function or does it just disable the menu?

Looking at the code, the OutHouse() function is marked private so unless you are using reflection (which I highly doubt) your back button isn't calling the OutHouse() function and as a result timeScale is never being set back to 1.

I recommend you install the Unity extension for VS or VS Code which will allow you to attach to the editor and set break points to check if your function gets called and from where. However for now you can put a Debug.Log() line in your OutHouse() function to ensure it's getting called when expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see how the OutHouse is not called here indeed. I am completely new to Unity and C#, mind pointing me in the way of adding it in there? :)

Comment: My recommendation would be to move the code that detects the back key being pressed into this class since it is part of the menu's behaviour so should be contained within it, and then when keypress is detected call the function. 


Another option is to make the function public and wherever you are detecting the keypress, getting a reference to the menu and invoking it. But this would be bad architecture in my opinion. If this solved your problem then it'd be great if you could accept answer ^-^

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I found the issue. I forgot to add the On Click () function in Unity. I set that to Housemenu.Outhouse and now it works :)

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: A good way of giving back, is to click the "accept answer" button on my post as it will reward the answerer with reputation which is required to access some of the features of the site.

Comment: I am sorry, still new to this. There you go :)